# Is there a way to create a script on Jupyter Notebook where I can run one notebook after another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have about 10 notebooks that I would like to run one after another and right now I do that manually, I was wondering if there was a way on Jupyter that I can run each notebook through one notebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually achieve this by using the following command:

```ipython
%run /path-of-the-notebook-that-has-to-be-run/notebook.ipynb
```

You can find more details in this [documentation about running a Jupyter Notebook from another Jupyter Notebook](https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/user-guide/notebooks-and-dashboards/notebooks/jupyter-notebooks/running-jupy-notebooks.html#:%7E:text=Running%20a%20Jupyter%20Notebook%20from%20Another%20Jupyter%20Notebook&text=From%20the%20left%20Sidebar%2C%20select,want%20to%20run%20another%20notebook.&text=Click%20Run.).

Comment: @Nathes Please, accept this answer if this has worked for you

Comment: This is perfect, thanks for linking in the documentation too.